# dplyr select column based on string match

Tags: r, dplyr

I am wanting to order my columns of a data frame by string matches.

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data.frame(start_a = 1,
           start_f = 3,
           end_a = 5,
           end_f = 7,
           middle_a= 9,
           middle_f = 11)
```

- For example I want to select `start_f, start_a, middle_f, middle_a, end_f ,end_a`
- I am attempting to do so with `data %>% select(matches("(start|middle|end)_(f|a)")))`, so that the order I have typed within the matches is the order that I want the columns to be selected.
- Desired output would be `data[c(2,1,6,5,4,3)]`

Comment: Could `relocate` be useful? https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/relocate.html You might have to use the function multiple times to reorder over multiple criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct the columns in the order that you want with `outer`.

```
order1 <- c('start', 'middle', 'end')
order2 <- c('f', 'a')
cols <- c(t(outer(order1, order2, paste, sep = '_')))
cols
#[1] "start_f"  "start_a"  "middle_f" "middle_a" "end_f"    "end_a" 

data[cols]
#  start_f start_a middle_f middle_a end_f end_a
#1       3       1       11        9     7     5
```

If not all combinations of `order1` and `order2` are present in the data we can use `any_of` which will select only the columns present in `data` without giving any error.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% select(any_of(cols))
```

---

To select based on pattern in names.

```
order1 <- c('start', 'middle', 'end')
order2 <- c('f', 'a')
pattern <- c(t(outer(order1, order2, function(x, y) sprintf('^%s_%s.*', x, y))))
pattern
#[1] "^start_f.*"  "^start_a.*"  "^middle_f.*" "^middle_a.*" "^end_f.*" "^end_a.*" 
cols <- names(data)

data[sapply(pattern, function(x) grep(x, cols))]

#  start_f start_a middle_f middle_a end_f end_a
#1       3       1       11        9     7     5
```

Comment: Maybe I should have been more explicit that the second group "f "and "a" that I try to get are in reality longer variable names, therefore a literal construction (as you show) wouldn't quite get what I am after. I didn't know if there was a regex type solution that would save typing out f and a in full?

Comment: I added a regex based solution. I am not sure if it will work for your actual data though.

Comment: The pattern based solution works and is what I was after.